# mix.js() is missing required parameter

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-mix

I use Vue with Laravel. But I get this error "mix.js() is missing required parameter" when I run
`npm run watch`.
Here is my code:

```
const mix = require("laravel-mix");
mix.js("resources/js/app.js", "public/js").vue();
mix.sass("public/assets/scss/style.scss", "public/assets/css");
mix.browserSync("127.0.0.1:8000");
```

Please share with me how to handle this error.

Comment: You're certain it's from this line of code? Your usage matches the example at https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/mix and https://laravel-mix.com/docs/6.0/vue.

Answer (score 1):

Change in version works well with  laravel 7.3.* see link below

The solution was to change to version ^6.0.6 in package.json and run npm install, as the .vue() call is a new feature in Laravel Mix 6.

```
"devDependencies": {
    // ...
    "laravel-mix": "^6.0.6",
    // ...
},
```

Then on webpack.mix.js.

`mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js').vue();`

https://nono.ma/assertionerror-mix-js-is-missing-required-parameter-1-entry